# Trouble with webscraping, how to NA when no results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have several URLs which link to Hotel pages and I would like to scrape some data from it.

I'm using the following this script, but I would like to update it:

```
data=[]

for i in range(0,10):
    url = final_list[i]
    driver2 = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver2.get(url)  
    sleep(randint(10,20))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver2.page_source, 'html.parser')

    my_table2 = soup.find_all(class_=['title-2', 'rating-score body-3'])
    
    review=soup.find_all(class_='reviews')[-1]
    
    try:
        price=soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'price'})[-1] 
    except:
        price=soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'price'})

    for tag in my_table2:
        data.append(tag.text.strip())
        
    for p in price:
        data.append(p)
        
    for r in review:
        data.append(r)
```

But here's the problem, `tag.text.strip()` scrape rating numbers like here :

[image: rating]

It will strip the number rating into alone value but some hotels don't have the same amout of ratings. Here's a hotel with 7 ratings, the default number is 8. Some have seven ratings, other six, and so on. So in the end, my dataframe is quite screwed. If the hotel doesn't have 8 ratings, the value will be shifted.

My question is : How to tell the script "if there is a value in this tag.text.strip(i) so put the value but if there isn't put None. And of course made that for the eight value.

I tried several things like :

```
for tag in my_table2:
    for i in tag.text.strip()[i]:
        if i:
            data.append(i)
        else:
            data.append(None)
```

But unfortunately, that goes nowhere, so if you could help to figure out the answer, it would be awesome :)

If that could help you, I put link on Hotel that I'm scraping :

https://www.hostelworld.com/pwa/hosteldetails.php/Itaca-Hostel/Barcelona/1279?from=2020-11-21&to=2020-11-22&guests=1

The number ratings are at the end

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add some example HTML code? e.g. one with 6 ratings and one with 8 ratings?

Comment: What about using a dictionary for your `data`? e.g. `data['price'] = p   data['review'] = r`?

Comment: What do you mean ? Yeah just give me 2 minutes, I will check the html and update my post

Comment: Put all the html would be too long, so I put the link on some hotels.

Comment: Can you add a link with 6 or 8 ratings?

Comment: I didn't find it weirdly, I don't understand. I just deleted the last columns and let seven rating and it worked fine I guess. But I would like to know how to deal with non value nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few suggestions:

- Put your data in a dictionary. You don't have to assume that all tags are present and the order of the tags doesn't matter. You can get the labels and the corresponding ratings with

  ```
  rating_labels = soup.find_all(class_=['rating-label body-3'])
  rating_scores = soup.find_all(class_=['rating-score body-3'])
  ```

  and then iterate over both lists with `zip`
- move your `driver` outside of the loop, opening it once is enough
- don't use `wait` but you use Selenium's wait functions. You can wait for a particular element to be present or populated with `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(your_element)`

  https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html
- Cache your scraped HTML code to a file. It's faster for you and politer to the website you are scraping

---

```
import selenium
import selenium.webdriver
import time
import random
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = []

final_list = [
    'https://www.hostelworld.com/pwa/hosteldetails.php/Itaca-Hostel/Barcelona/1279?from=2020-11-21&to=2020-11-22&guests=1',
    'https://www.hostelworld.com/pwa/hosteldetails.php/Be-Ramblas-Hostel/Barcelona/435?from=2020-11-27&to=2020-11-28&guests=1'
]

# load your driver only once to save time
driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()

for url in final_list:
    data.append({})

    # cache the HTML code to the filesystem
    # generate a filename from the URL where all non-alphanumeric characters (e.g. :/) are replaced with underscores _
    filename = ''.join([s if s.isalnum() else '_' for s in url])
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        driver.get(url)
        
        # better use selenium's wait functions here  
        time.sleep(random.randint(10, 20))
        source = driver.page_source
        with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(source)
    else:
        with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            source = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

    review = soup.find_all(class_='reviews')[-1]
    
    try:
        price = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'price'})[-1] 
    except:
        price = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'price'})

    data[-1]['name'] = soup.find_all(class_=['title-2'])[0].text.strip()
    
    rating_labels = soup.find_all(class_=['rating-label body-3'])
    rating_scores = soup.find_all(class_=['rating-score body-3'])
    assert len(rating_labels) == len(rating_scores)
    for label, score in zip(rating_labels, rating_scores):
        data[-1][label.text.strip()] = score.text.strip()
    
    data[-1]['price'] = price.text.strip()
    data[-1]['review'] = review.text.strip()
```

- The data can then be easily put in a nicely formatted table using Pandas

  ```
  import pandas as pd
  df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  df
  ```

[image]

- If some data is missing/incomplete, Pandas will replace it with 'NaN'

  ```
  data.append(data[0].copy())
  del(data[-1]['Staff'])
  data[-1]['name'] = 'Incomplete Hostel'
  pd.DataFrame(data)
  ```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this awesome answer :) I will check it out asap !

Comment: Hello :) Why the use of isalnum ? I wonder. Actually I don't understand the first part before the 'try'

Comment: @LaurieFalcon: It converts the URL to a string which can be stored on most filesystems. isalnum() returns True for alphanumeric characters, i.e. all the special characters get converted to underscores.

Comment: You want to store on filesystem to be polite to the site ? That's the point ? :)

Comment: @LaurieFalcon: Yes, it's also much faster. If I change the scraping logic, I don't have to download all files again. If I want to update the content, I just delete the files.

Comment: Ok I didn't understood all the code for this part for now but thank for the tip !

Comment: @MaximilianPeters is it possible to add relevant comments wherever applicable to your proposed solution? I think then the code would be much more readable. For example, say a one-line comment for  `isalnum`, `cache html code`, `data[-1]['price']` etc. Reason for why selenium wait() and not python core class `wait` etc.

Comment: @mnm: good idea! add some comments to the relevant sections and link to Selenium's wait functions

Comment: @MaximilianPeters on behalf of the community, I take the responsibility in felicitating your prompt action, to improve code readability. plus 1'ed the answer. thanks.